# iPhone zoom doesn't zoom in on text in menu buttons

Tags: iphone, html, css, zooming

When I look at my page on an iPhone, I see the page in a zoomed out mode. This is fine, and all dimensions fit to each other of boxes etc.

**But not the text.** The text size is bigger compared to other sizes on this zoomed view.

This is ok for the text content on the page. Then it's easier to read the text on the phone, and the content text is not fixed but floats and fits to the container.

But the text on buttons as in the main menu on the page is also not reduced in size by the same percentage. And here there is a problem - the main menu bar is then suddenly to wide because everything else is shrunk more than this.

My menu's width is not fixed but fits to the text-width. So when the text-width suddenly is larger than usual, the menu bar is wider than usual too.

I can't give a screen shot, but I hope this is a known issue. As an example see this simulator (it seems to show the problem as on the iPhone):
http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator.php?u=http://w3schools.com#

And compare the normal site: http://w3schools.com/

This site also have this problem with e.g. the menu on the right on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Mabye `text-size-adjust` can help you.

```
.css {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust:    none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:     none;
    text-size-adjust:         none;
}
```

This will allow your text to be smaller than the default value your phones browser allow.

Note: test it on a real phone since "There is a bug in Webkit-based desktop browsers. If -webkit-text-size-adjust is explicitely set to none, Webkit-based desktop browsers, like Chrome or Safari, instead of ignoring the property, will prevent the user to zoom in or out the Web page"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-size-adjust

Comment: If I set this to everything on the page, then the page is not zoomed out at all. Can't I instead make the text size have the same amount of zoom as the rest instead of removing all zoom?

Comment: Have you tested it on a real phone. "There is a bug in Webkit-based desktop browsers. If -webkit-text-size-adjust is explicitely set to none, Webkit-based desktop browsers, like Chrome or Safari, instead of ignoring the property, will prevent the user to zoom in or out the Web page"